# How can I pass values from obj-C to a quartz composer view?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, quartz-graphics

In a .xib for an application I'm working on, I have a quartz composer viewer object (QCView) in the window. I also have a patch controller (QCPatchController). The patch controller has its own class files in xCode, but they aren't doing anything right now. Following the apple docs, I was able to bind some values within the .nib file so if I edited a text field, it would pass this value to a published input on the QC document. Unfortunately, these docs say nothing about how to pass values programatically. How can I pass values (in code) to a QC patch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `-setValue:forKeyPath:`. For example:

```
[patchController setValue:@"foo" forKeyPath:@"patch.stringinput.value"];
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I'm having a little trouble getting this to work. In QCPatchcontroller.m, I have a function `-(void)setAngle:(int)angle{
[self setValue:@"140" forKeyPath:@"patch.text.value"];
}`. (the (int)angle is for later use, ignore it for now). "text" is the name of the published input. In my app delegate.m, I have `#import "QCPatchController.h"` and `static QCPatchController *visualizer;` at the top and `[visualizer setAngle:50];` in my main (again, the argument does nothing yet). This seems to have no effect on the patch, it acts like the published input is still set to zero.

Comment: Not sure, I haven't really tried this before. Perhaps it doesn't work to pass a string as a number? Have you tried using [NSNumber numberWithFloat:140.0] instead of @"140" ?

Comment: Good thinking, I didn't even notice that. Still not working though, the patch won't respond. No one seems to have done this, which is odd. QC is very simple and robust, I would think it would be perfect for non-aqua animated UIs.

Comment: Looking at the documentation a bit more, it seems that QCView (the view that displays your composition) adopts the QCCompositionRenderer protocol, which defines the method -setValue:forInputKey:. This might be what you're looking for. I think QCPatchController is just some wrapper for using bindings (which you don't want here).

Comment: OK, good find. I now have, in my app delegate, `static QCView *visualizer;` and `[visualizer setValue:40.0 forInputKey:@"text"];`. It now compiles with the warning `warning: 'QCView' may not respond to '-setValue:forInputKey:'`. Odd... The patch still does nothing.